# How to append user input to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, append

I am trying to append both string and numbers (menu item and menu price) of user input to 2 existing arrays. I know I will need vectors and `std` but how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a unordered_map to store strings and their respective int values.

```
unordered_map<string,int>m;
string s;
int n;
cin>>s;
cin>>n;
map[string]=int.
```

or if want to to specifically want to store in vectors create vectors of type string and int

```
vector<string>s;
vector<int>n;
string st;
int mp;
cin>>st;
s.push_back(st);
cin>>mp;
n.push_back(mp);
```

Comment: I made a more specific question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383701/can-i-have-multiple-whiles-in-do-while-loop