# How to use stoi to distinguish char input and integer input?

Tags: c++, arrays, do-while

I am trying to write a code that allows users to add or remove menu items from the "vending machine." I have the vending machine code working, but how do I append or delete items from the menu? I have set "c" for checkout, "a" for add item, and "r" for delete item.
I have edited my code (check edited code at bottom) so that everything is in a function but I have trouble with separating my `integer` inputs and `char` inputs in the `if statement` in the main. I know there is a syntax error but I am not sure how to use `stoi`. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Examples of the output I want:

Vending machine:

----Items----

(5 listed below)

what item would you like to buy? Enter "c" to checkout, "a" for add item and "r" for remove item.

-If user input is an integer, then run the `enterSelection` function

-If user input is a character (c, a, or r) , then:

1. if "c" , then run `checkout` function
2. if "a", What Item would you like to add and for what price? Then add to `menuItems`.
3. if  "r", what item would you like to remove (enter a number)? Then `erase` the item from `menuItems`.

Then print: "User input" has been added/removed from the menu.

When the menu is displayed again, the user edit will show.

Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
**input item;** //here is my error

std::vector<string> menuItems = {"Popcorn", "Coconut Clusters" , "Granola Bar" , "Trail Mix" , "Chocolate"};

std::vector<float> cost = {2, 3, 2.50, 1.50, 1};


void vendingMachine() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        cout << i + 1 << ". " << menuItems[i] << ": $" << cost[i] << endl;

}


int main() {

    cout.precision(2);
    cout << std::fixed;

    cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
    cout << "----Items------" << endl;

    vendingMachine();
    cout << "Enter 0 to checkout" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a to add items" << endl;
    cout << "Enter r to remove items" << endl;
    
    
    float total;
    total = 0;

    

    do {
        cout << "Enter your selection: " << flush;
        
        cin >> item;
       
        item = item - 1;
        
        cout << menuItems[item] << ": $" << cost[item] << " has been added to cart." << endl;
        total = total + cost[item];

    } while (item != -1); {

    cout << "                         " << endl;
    cout << "Proceding to checkout..." << endl;
    cout << "========================" << endl;

    cout << "Amount due: $" << total << endl;


    cout << "Insert money here: $" << flush;
    float money;
    cin >> money;

    while (money < total) {
        float amountOwed = total - money;
        cout << "Please insert another $" << amountOwed << endl;

        cout << "Enter amount: $" << flush;
        float payment;
        cin >> payment;
        money += payment;
    }
    if (money > total) {
        float change = money - total;
        cout << "Thank you! You have $" << change << " change." << endl;
    }

    if (money == total) {
        cout << "Thank you! Have a nice day!." << endl;
    }
    } while (item != "a") {
        if (item == "a") {
        cout << "What item would you like to add: " << flush;
        string add;
        cin >> add;
        menuItems.push_back(add);
      }
    } while (item != "r") {
        if (item == "r") {
      cout << "What item would you like to remove: " << flush;
      string remove;
      cin >> remove;
      menuItems.erase(remove);
      }
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Edited code: (more organized but does not run)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

stringstream item;
float total;

std::vector<string> menuItems = {"Popcorn", "Coconut Clusters" , "Granola Bar" , "Trail Mix" , "Chocolate"};

std::vector<float> cost = {2, 3, 2.50, 1.50, 1};


void vendingMachine() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

        cout << i + 1 << ". " << menuItems[i] << ": $" << cost[i] << endl;

}

void enterSelection() {
  total = 0;

  cout << "Enter your selection: " << flush;
        
        cin >> item;
       
        item = item - 1;
        
        cout << menuItems[item] << ": $" << cost[item] << " has been added to cart." << endl;
        total = total + cost[item];

}

void checkout() {
  cout << "                         " << endl;
  cout << "Proceding to checkout..." << endl;
  cout << "========================" << endl;

  cout << "Amount due: $" << total << endl;


  cout << "Insert money here: $" << flush;
  float money;
  cin >> money;

  while (money < total) {
    float amountOwed = total - money;
    cout << "Please insert another $" << amountOwed << endl;

    cout << "Enter amount: $" << flush;
    float payment;
    cin >> payment;
    money += payment;
    }
    if (money > total) {
        float change = money - total;
        cout << "Thank you! You have $" << change << " change." << endl;
    }

    if (money == total) {
        cout << "Thank you! Have a nice day!." << endl;
    }
}

void add() {
  cout << "What item would you like to add: " << flush;
  string add;
  cin >> add;
  menuItems.push_back(add);
    
}

void remove() {
    cout << "What item would you like to remove (enter a number): " << flush;
    int remove;
    cin >> remove;
    menuItems.erase(remove);
}


int main() {

  cout.precision(2);
  cout << std::fixed;

  cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
  cout << "----Items------" << endl;

  vendingMachine();
  cout << "Enter c to checkout" << endl;
  cout << "Enter a to add items" << endl;
  cout << "Enter r to remove items" << endl;
    

  enterSelection();

  if (item == int) {
    enterSelection();
  } else if (item = "c") {
    checkout();
  } else if (item = "a") {
    add();
  } else if (item = "r") {
    remove();
  }
  else {
    cout << "Please enter a number or press c to checkout, a to add item, or r to remove item: " << flush;
  }

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this code `while (item != -1 != "+", "-");` supposed to do?

Comment: Logical and `&&` and logical or `||` allow you to have compound tests (`i > 5 && y < 3`).

Comment: `item` is an `int`, so it will never contain `"+"` or `"-"`.

Comment: The most obvious problem is that you are expecting the user to enter a string "0", "+" or "-" but you have declared your `item` variable as an `int`. An `int` can't have the value of `+` or `-`.

Comment: Really I suggest you make life easy for yourself and left the user enter 0, 1, or 2 for the different options. Then you can use an `int` for your variable.

Comment: Now that you've changed your `while` condition, can you show some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: maybe instead of entering "+" for add item, and "-" for remove item, I should do "a" for add and "r" for remove

Comment: You need to change the `item` variable from an `int` to a `std::string` if you are going to use non integer values. An `int` is always an `int` if you enter anything else in the input the input will fail.

Comment: What do you mean by *"append or delete items from the menu"*? Do you want a menu item to not be available after it's selected once?

Comment: yes thats what i mean; if they select "r" then that item is deleted from the vending machine menu

Comment: Ok, are you open to using a `vector` instead of an array? That would make things much easier.

Comment: yes, I have never used it before but I am willing to try

Comment: I have been researching the `string::append` but I am not sure if that is what I should use

Comment: Give it a shot yourself first. Take a look at [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). There are useful functions to do what you want. e.g `erase` will erase an element.

Comment: You are trying to do at least two new things at once: a menu loop, and adding/removing elements in a container. Tackle these problems separately, and get them working perfectly in isolation, before you attempt to dovetail them.